# Why ffmpeg/mplayer2 play sloppy something that vlc plays well?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, vlc, mplayer

While trying to play with mplayer2 or stream with ffmpeg, the video has a slight delay about every 12 seconds. Sometimes leading to distorted picture. But the same input plays back perfectly with vlc. What could be the reason for this?

mplayer2 shows it's infamous "YOUR SYSTEM IS TOO SLOW TO PLAY THIS", but neither of its suggestions make difference.

Comment: my guess is VLC is dropping frames more aggressively.  mplayer has some parameters to do some things similar, though it might not be as good as VLC still

Comment: Another option is that VLC makes uses of hardware accelerated decoding which may not be supported by the mplayer2 release in question.